# Nested hasOne & hasMany relationships in laravel nova's show resource page

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Before I updated Nova when I add a hasOne relation in my resource class it automatically added the hasMany and hasOne relations from the related resource class.

For example:

I have a UserResource class which has `HasOne::make('Parent')->exceptOnForms()`
Basically a User can be a parent, child etc.

And then I have a ParentResource which also has `HasMany::make('Addresses')->exceptOnForms()`
Basically a Parent can have multiple addresses.

Now before I update Nova from 4.20.2 to 4.32.11 everything worked great. The addresses were being loaded when I am on the UserResource but now it's not.

Anyone knows if anything happened?